# Error when Installing CrystalReport SAP VS 2010

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I using VS 2010. but when i add a crystal report to my WPF Application, i get a page with message

> "Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010 is a free download for adding
>   presentation quality reports to WPF, WinForms, and ASP.Net Web Sites.
>
> Major new features include:
>
> ```
> 64-bit runtime
> WPF viewer
> Enhanced embedded report designer
> Support for exporting to XLSX
> ```
>
> Learn more and download Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010 today

Then i am trying to download and [instal this SAP Crystal Report version](http://scn.sap.com/people/coy.yonce/blog/2010/11/12/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio-2010-production-release-now-available) on my PC. 
But this error appear:

[image]

Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My first is are you trying installing the right bit version for your operating system? But without more data about your computer setup we have nothing to go on.

Comment: i think i am using the right bit version for my operating system, i am installing SAP Crystal Report 32 bit.